# Is there a recommended approach for handling AppConfig when designing an app for Django 1.6 and 1.7?

Tags: python, django, version-compatibility

[Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/) has [introduced a new way for handling application configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.verbose_name) that is independent of `models.py`. However the method for using the new `AppConfig` requires this line:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
```

Unfortunately, this will break in Django 1.6 as there is no `apps` module.

**Is it possible to have an app be compatible with 1.6 and 1.7 using conditional imports, or is it a matter of split code bases?** If so, are is there a recommend guide, preferably from the Django developers on how to do so?

Comment: I don't know if you'll get an official guide or recommendation, but have you tried, maybe, simply adding the `apps` module from 1.7 to your Django 1.6 project and trying to manually integrate it? I'm sure there'll be some rough edges, but it's still a recent addition, so it can't break things up too much. Also, it only has like, [two files](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/apps), so it can't be *a lot* of work, can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using AppConfig only if django version >= 1.7 (take that into account in __ init __.py file too):

```
# myapp/apps.py
from django import VERSION as DJANGO_VERSION
if DJANGO_VERSION >= (1, 7):
    from django.apps import AppConfig
    class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
        ...

# myapp/__init__.py
from django import VERSION as DJANGO_VERSION
if DJANGO_VERSION >= (1, 7):
    default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and it seems to work ok. I chose it because I prefer explicit checks to exceptions.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure about officially django suggested way, but that is how I would do it:

```
# myapp/apps.py

try:
    from django.apps import AppConfig
except ImportError:
    AppConfig = object

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    # put all the necessary stuff for AppConfig

# myapp/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

This way if it's django>=1.7 it will use this `MyAppConfig`, otherwise `myapp/apps.py` module will be simply ignored, and it will work the same as before for django<1.7